# Should I declare imports at the beginning of a file or somewhere else?

Tags: python, import, pycodestyle

I've read [an article about AsyncIO](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) and noticed something. Here is a code from that article:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# countasync.py

import asyncio

async def count():
    print("One")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Two")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(count(), count(), count())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    s = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f"{__file__} executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
```

Why does `import time` declared after `if __name__ == "__main__"` not at the beginning of document? According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) "Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants". As I know there are some weird packages (such as in Twisted) which you should import at some special place. But why does the author placed `import time` here? Is there any sense?

Comment: Because time is only used when that file is run directly, not when it's imported from elsewhere.

Comment: I fully agree with @jonrsharpe . When importing this file from another script and if `import time` was at the top, you will be left with the useless `time` module. A lighter code is better! It also improves readability, the `time` module is only there for the test. Finally, people without the test libraries can still run the `count()` and `main()` functions.